# Icelandair flight to America: check in for second leg at Keflavik?

Tags: check-in, icelandair

I have an Icelandair flight from Paris CDG to Newark with a stopover in Keflavik. I checked in online for the first leg (to Keflavik) and have a boarding pass. As often for flights to the US, I can't check in online for the second.

Do I need to get the boarding pass for the second leg in Paris, or is it possible to get in in Keflavik (ideally from within the security area)? The check-in line in Paris is really long and slow, so I'm thinking it might be faster to skip the line here and get the second boarding pass there.

Comment: I'd try to check in in Paris unless I had something better to do (especially if that thing is to board the airplane!).  But if the check-in line were truly slow and long, I'd ask at the gate -- those terminals have the capacity to issue boarding passes, too.  The decision on how to proceed also depends on the amount of time you expect to have in Keflavik.  Is it a tight connection?

Comment: That is strange - just last week I flew from Europe to the US via Keflavik, and managed to check in online for both parts of the trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it in Keflavik airside. There are service desks in Terminal C (near gate C22, arrival from EU) and Terminal D (near gate D15, departure to US)

https://www.icelandair.com/support/pre-flight/connecting-at-keflavik/

> You will ordinarily receive a boarding card for each flight. If you do not have a boarding card for your second flight, please contact the Icelandair service desk representative at Keflavík airport.